# PTIJ: The truth about the seder plate

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In Peter David's *Star Trek* novel *Imzadi*, the villains are named Betzah, Zeroah, Charoset, Chazeret, Karpas and Maror.

What does Chazal tell us about the dark truth concerning the denizens of the seder plate?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).